# shiny datatable get data

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

I want to get all data from a datatable in Shiny. I know that there are methods to refer to a selected row or cell but I need to get the data from a whole editable datatable regardless selection status.
I can use `input[[datatable_id_rows_all]]` to get the indices of active rows. Is there any way to catch the rest of the info?